# Can't get the TypeORM tests to run

Tags: typeorm

I'm trying to run the TypeORM tests locally. I'm using the Docker images to run all the databases by simply running:

```
docker-compose up
```

I copied `ormconfig.json.dist` to `ormconfig.json` and then I run:

```
npm run compile ; npm run test
```

It crashes with this error:

```
> npm run compile ; npm run test

> typeorm@0.2.25 compile C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Flexpoint Tech\js\typeorm
> rimraf ./build && tsc


> typeorm@0.2.25 test C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Flexpoint Tech\js\typeorm
> rimraf ./build && tsc && mocha --file ./build/compiled/test/utils/test-setup.js --bail --recursive --timeout 60000 ./build/compiled/test



  √ github issues > #3158 Cannot run sync a second time (475ms)
  √ github issues > #3588 Migration:generate issue with onUpdate using mysql 8.0 (116ms)
  benchmark > bulk-save > case1
connecting
    1) "before all" hook for "testing bulk save of 10.000 objects"
    2) "after all" hook for "testing bulk save of 10.000 objects"


  2 passing (1m)
  2 failing

  1) benchmark > bulk-save > case1
       "before all" hook for "testing bulk save of 10.000 objects":
     Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\Users\pupeno\Documents\Flexpoint Tech\js\typeorm\build\compiled\test\benchmark\bulk-save-case1\bulk-save-case1.js)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:551:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:494:7)

  2) benchmark > bulk-save > case1
       "after all" hook for "testing bulk save of 10.000 objects":
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
      at Object.closeTestingConnections (test\utils\test-utils.ts:285:36)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\benchmark\bulk-save-case1\bulk-save-case1.ts:16:17)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:458:21)



npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! typeorm@0.2.25 test: `rimraf ./build && tsc && mocha --file ./build/compiled/test/utils/test-setup.js --bail --recursive --timeout 60000 ./build/compiled/test`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the typeorm@0.2.25 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pupeno\scoop\persist\nodejs\cache\_logs\2020-07-11T09_15_28_115Z-debug.log
```

Trying to debug what's going on, as far as I can see, it times out when connecting to the PostgreSQL database, but the other databases seem to work and connecting with my PSQL client (DataGrip) using the same credentials as in `ormconfig.json` also works.

Another thing I tried is not starting the docker image, instead starting my own local PostgreSQL, setting up a user and database with the correct credentials and attempt to run the tests. Same error.

I'm building an app that uses TypeORM and connects to that same PostgreSQL successfully. Their tests seem to be passing: https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/typeorm/typeorm/1319/workflows/cf7bf4d0-5c6f-485f-803b-64eff385676b/jobs/2012

Any ideas what else to try or what could be going on?

Comment: Have you tried other tests with `postgres` driver? Do they all fail? By the way there is a funny comment here https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/906d97fc8dbf1dba8f4e579a4f5bfead83af36ab/test/github-issues/3158/issue-3158.ts#L12 : `todo(AlexMesser): 
 check why tests are failing under postgres driver` is makes you wander.

Comment: I commented the failing tests out and other tests failed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging,

Those test are executed vs all database engines, if you are not interested in tests other than PostgreSQL then set `skip` flag in `ormconfig.json` for other engines.

In other cases you need to resolve issues for other dbs:

I found that one reason of the issue is that MariaDB disallows connections from exterior networks, therefore if container runs in the composer network it is not possible to connect to it from the host network (which is where you run npm test).
To overcame this:

1. Start docker-compose with a named project (this will give a name for network:)
   `docker-compose -p test up -d`
2. Execute SQL that will allow root to connect from any host:
   `docker-compose -p test run --rm mariadb mysql -hmariadb -uroot -padmin -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin' WITH GRANT OPTION;\nFLUSH PRIVILEGES;"`

After that, `npm run test` for mariaDB is passing.

MariaDB container [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) mention `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST` which should do the same job - but from unknown reason, it is not working.

Remember to use down with project name: `docker-compose -p test down`

Also I found that `ormconfig.json` states that test for SAP database are not skipped but, SAP DB engine is not enabled in `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: How do you know it was MariaDB? I did try to follow your steps here, but I'm getting exactly the same error.

Comment: I found it by skiping it in ormconfig.json file